# SQL: Is there a clever way to show text data in pivoted columns without having inner queries or aggregate functions?

Tags: sql, pivot, aggregate, crosstab, unpivot

I have a bunch of data (multiple rows for each unique reference) that needs to be in one row with multiple columns. Some of columns that need to be used have to be further split out as they hold more than one value. This has been done using an unpivot. I now have 7 columns from this 1 original column and it now needs to display statuses against the new 7 columns. I cannot however use a pivot as I need to see the various statuses in the 7 columns and not a min, max or a count.

[image]

Comment: The data is supposed to show where a client is in a process. I have an overall status grouping but the business is also wanting a dataset showing all the detail behind it. Unfortunately the tables I need to use are set up allowing for multiple rows but this data needs to be at client level.

Comment: Can you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to show us your data model? It would be helpful in understanding the problem.

Comment: You might find it better to create a set of client-specific rows, and present the data in more of a tabular format.  Consuming dynamic pivoted data can be a real pain in the butt.

Comment: Can you post some sample data, your table structure and the expected results?  Or as @BrandonBoone suggested use a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to give us the data. At this time it would be very difficult to answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform this type of shift with a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function.

Static Pivot (See [SQL Fiddle for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79213/2)):

```
select *
from 
(
  select reference, jobtypesplit, status
  from t1
) x
pivot
(
  min(status)
  for jobtypesplit in ([DDS], [MBN], [LPN], [WEN], [LLP], [OPE], [SSE])
) p
```

This can also be done dynamically (See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79213/6))

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(jobtypesplit) 
                  FROM t1 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT reference, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select reference, jobtypesplit, status
                from t1
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(status)
                for jobtypesplit in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: I can't use min() as it will only bring back the 'Allocated' status.

Comment: Based on the expected result you requested, it is providing the correct result.  Can you post additional data that will show multiple items for the same jobtypesplit?  If you have multiple status' for a jobtypesplit then how do you determine which one you want?

Comment: Can you join the statuses with numeric mappings that will work correctly with a min()?

Comment: @baxter yes that us an option as well. But there needs to be some indication as to which status should be grabbed if you only want one. There has to be a deciding factor somewhere and nothing was presented in the OP.